# SQL average and Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, average

I'm trying to merge these two statements into one query to get the a list of product names(or ids) against the average of their TTFF data, and I'm stuck.

```
select AVG(TTFF) from TTFFdata group by product_id

select product.product_name, count(*) from product join TTFFdata on product.product_id = TTFFdata.product_id
```

I've looked into using a temporary table (`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS averages AS (select AVG(TTFF) from TTFFdata group by product_id)`) but couldn't get that to work with a join.

Anyone able to help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the components.  Your second query is missing a `group by`.  This would seem to be what you want:

```
select p.product_name, count(t.product_id), avg(t.TTFF)
from product p left join
     TTFFdata t
     on p.product_id = t.product_id
group by p.product_name
```

Comment: Works now - I think it was just a case of uppercase name needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to do group by on product_id, product_name for two reasons. One is, you can select product id along with product name. Second reason is, If the product name is not unique then it may give wrong results(this may be a rare scenario like product name is same but it differs based on other columns like version or model). The below is the final query.

```
select Product.product_id, 
product_name,
AVG(TTFF) as Avg_TTFF 
from Product
inner join
TTFFdata
on Product.product_id = TTFFdata.product_id
group by Product.product_id,Product.product_name
```

## TTFFdata:

[image]

## product:

[image]

## Output:

[image]